# In Java I am struggling to load a webpage

Tags: java

```
private class OutputAction implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        myModel.addSummaryAndDetailPagesWriter("./html/summary.html");
        myModel.perform();
        try
        {

            myPage.setPage("/html/summary.html");
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            myTf.setText("You tried to view the file and it broke");
        }

    }

}
```

For what ever reason I cant load the page. I have tried using google as a dummie URL and it works. Assume perform writes the file to that directory. Anyone have an insight?

Comment: What is myPage, myModel, myTf ?

Comment: myTf is a JTextField myModel is a model the method takes in a directory and will write to that directory myPage is a JEditorPane

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what sort of object `myModel` or `myPage` are, but the obvious conclusion is that the argument to methods like `addSummaryAndDetailPagesWriter` and `setPage` must be a URL, not a path to a file.

Comment: myPage is a JEditorPane and myModel is a model trying to use a mvc. so this is in my view. the addSummaryAndDetailPagesWriter method takes in a file directory and setpage should also be able to use a string which leads to a url

Comment: You've got `./html/summary.html` in one place and  `/html/summary.html` in another; those are very different paths unless the current working directory is the root of the filesystem. Is the problem just that the second path is missing that "." ?

Comment: Unfortunately no that is not the problem. I've made progress in that the html file is displayed but only the title shows up. I'm not sure why only a portion of the file would display.

Comment: To be more precise I've loaded the page properly using chrome and safari with the file directory given but the mini web-browser in java I have and the GUI I am developing in the code above both fail to load the page and only display the title